# Move next available column value to previous available column space in informatica

Tags: informatica

0
votes

1 view
Hi,
I have a scenario, where in we have a single record and multiple columns like this
Record_number cd1 cd2 cd3 cd4 cd5 cd6 cd7 cd8 cd9

---

Here are values for the for the above record
123           12 null 13 14 null 15 16 17 null
Here we have value for cd1 and not for cd2 and we have value for cd3 so cd2 is empty so cd3 should get into cd2 since it was empty so we should move the next available values to previous available spaces.

Does anyone know how to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this can be easily done using an **expression transformation**.

Comment: Hi, Here is the question, please take a look.   Thank u so much for your reply. Just making sure whether you got my question clearly? Here is my scenario again Only single record column s Record number cd1 cd2 cd3 ---- cd12 and values for this record are record number 123 cd1 20 cd2 null cd3 40---- cd12 since cd2 is null the next value cd3 has value so this value should come into cd2 as it empty like that all the values containing columns should be backwarded to the empty previous columns? Did u give your reply for this scenario? I appreciate your help. Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

First create a variable port that would concatenate all the non-null values using some separator, e.g.`|`, like:

```
IIF(ISNULL(cd1),'',cd1 || '|') ||
IIF(ISNULL(cd2),'',cd2 || '|') ||
...
IIF(ISNULL(cd9),'',cd9 || '|') ||
```

This should result in pipe delimited list with the nulls removed, e.g.:
`123|12|13|14|15|16|17|`

Next create an output port for each column, that would get the correct substring using index of the separator. I'll leave coding this part to you, but if you'd have issues, please let me know.

Comment: Thank u so much for your reply. Just making sure whether you got my question clearly? Here is my scenario again      Only single record column  s  Record number cd1 cd2 cd3 ---- cd12 and values for this record are record number 123 cd1 20 cd2 null cd3 40---- cd12 since cd2 is null the next value cd3 has value so this value should come into cd2 as it empty like that all the values containing columns should be backwarded to the empty previous columns? Did u give your reply for this scenario? I appreciate your help. Please let me know if your answer is for this?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the goal. Try it out, play around with it a bit to get familiar with the stuff and let me know in case of issues.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use an expression transformation as follows:

First concatenate all the ports in a single field using a delimiter (for example ',')

```
v_CONCAT:= cd1||','||cd2||','||cd3||','||cd4||','||cd5||','||cd6||','||cd7||','||cd8||','||cd9
```

Now create the output ports using regular expressions

```
o_cd1:=REG_EXTRACT(v_CONCAT,',*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*)',1)
o_cd2:=REG_EXTRACT(v_CONCAT,',*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*)',2)
o_cd3:=REG_EXTRACT(v_CONCAT,',*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*),*([^,]*)',3)
.
. 
and so on.
```

REG_EXTRACT extracts a substring from the input string that matches the regular expression.

- `()` - a group. There will be as many groups as your ports cd1-cd12
- `,*` - zero or more commas, if a value is null two commas will appear consecutively
- `[^,]` - anything other than comma
- `[^,]*` - zero or more of any character other than comma

The third parameter to REG_EXTRACT denotes which group you want as output. For o_cd1 we want the first non-NULL value, so it is 1 and for o_cd2, it is 2 and so on

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. Can u please help me in reg_extract syntax for 1 of the codes ex- o_cd1? CAn u say me the output for this column? Just curious about knowing how does that function work? and whats the output for this?

Comment: Updated the answer with explanation.

Comment: Hi Also I tried your logic just now, But if value in cd1 has 20 and cd2 has null and cd 3 has 30 this cd3 value '30' is not moving into cd2  which has null value. Instead values I am getting same.  CD1 20, cd2 null and cd3 null :(    Can u please provide me corrected logic?

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation. I implemented the same logic. But output is same as input. CD1 has 20, cd2 has null and cd3 has 30. This cd3 did not move into cd2? If possible can u correct this and let me know. But now I understood your logic after your explanation thanks :). Please provide me corrected logic if possible :)

Comment: Run the mapping in debugger and check how the concatenated string looks like, it should be 20,,30 etc. Then the logic should work.

Comment: CD1 has value 20 cd2 has null cd3 has 30 cd4 12 cd5 15    V_Concat value is 20,,30,12,     ,15    ,,,,,    ---- This is the v_concat ouput    And o_cd1 has 20, o_cd2 has null and o_cd3 has 30

Comment: Hi,  I copied the wrong logic. Its working absolutely fine. Sorry for the inconvenience. Glad you explained me in detail. Thank u :)

Comment: You are welcome! Glad it worked for you. You might want to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi Samik, Another scenario. If u can help me.   Here is my scenario.

My data comes here like this 1134567/9

and ETL should process as 11-3-4567/9

So i should pass a hyphen after first two bytes and then after next third byte another hypen should be passed. Whats the logic should be in expression transformation?



Thanks, Teja.

Comment: Answered the seperate qn you posted.